# Web Service NFE Prefeitura de São Paulo Erro 1402

Tags: c#, nfe

boa tarde.
Estou criando um código para acesso ao Web Service de NFE da Prefeitura de São Paulo, chamando o método de Pedido de Consulta de NF-e Emitidas.
Criei todo o código de integração, inclusive gerando o XML assinado pelo certificado digital e aparentemente está tudo correto com o código, mas ao fazer uso recebo um XML de retorno com o erro `1402 O CPF/CNPJ da assinatura da mensagem XML não tem acesso ao Tomador de Serviços
informado.`.
Alguém sabe qual a causa desse erro?

Answer (score 0):

Poste mais um pouco do código que faz a consulta. 
Esta fazendo o download através de qual WebService? Bom se for o servidor da Sefaz no caso você muito provavelmente estará fazendo uma manifestação destinatário e depois uma Distribuição

Bom Se for isso o conceito e:

Você vai colocar o CNPJ do destinatário que na maioria dos casos e você mesmo. Utilizando seu certificado digital (Do destinatário que no caso e você mesmo) irá fazer o processo citado acima. Manifestação e Distribuição.

Porque e preciso de manifestação e distribuição?

manifestação: você confirma que a NFe foi realmente emitida para você. Em outras palavras você diz para a sefaz: Sefaz essa NF-e realmente foi emitida para min, ok? (Manifestação de confirmar "Ciência da Operação")

Distribuição: faz uma distribuição pela chave da nf-e ou pelo nsu depende do caso.

Obs: A prefeitura de são paulo disponibiliza um download custom de NF-e? Ou e servidor da Sefaz de São paulo?